# GSM modem doesn't respond on at+cmgl command

Tags: serial-port, modem, at-command, pyserial

I'm writing a linux program which interact with gsm modem through AT-commands. Sometimes the modem respond on `at+cmgl="all"` command and return sms messages, sometimes the modem doesn't respond on this command(no answer, no ok, no error).

I use Python and pySerial, but it doesn't matter, because I tested the modem via bash terminal, send commands to the modem via `echo` and read answers from the modem via `cat /dev/ttyUSB0`. The same situation (sometimes it responds, sometimes not).

Comment: Do you send AT+CMGF=1 before you attempt to retrieve the messages?

Comment: You probably need to check if modem is really in command mode, by sending a simple "AT" null command and getting an "OK" response.

Comment: _dbasnett_, yes.
_sawdust_, I have sent `AT` command and have got `OK` in response. But the modem **doesn't** answer to `AT+CMGL="ALL"` command **sometimes**.

Comment: Just to make sure, you always use the string `"ALL"` and not `"all"` (because `"ALL"` is the only correct choice)?

Comment: _hlovdal_, I use both variants, and the modem answers "ALL" and "all" commands, and sometimes it answers neither "ALL" nor "all" commands.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    po.Write("AT+CHUP"+Environment.NewLine);
    po.Close();
    button3.Enabled = false;
    button1.Enabled = true;
}
```